# PHP captha image not working

Tags: captcha

I have tried this code to create a captcha image

```
    <?PHP
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
       $size=25;
       $captha_width=100;
       $captha_height=40;
       $text=rand(10000,99999);

       $captha=imagecreate($captha_width,$captha_height);
       imagecolorallocate($captha,192,192,192);
       $color=imagecolorallocate($captha,10,10,10);

    for($i=1;$i<30;++$i){
     $a1=rand(0,100);
     $a2=rand(0,100);
     $a3=rand(0,100);
     $a4=rand(0,100);

    imageline($captha,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$color);
    }
  imagettftext($captha,$size,0,15,30,$color,'face.ttf',$text);
  imagejpeg($captha);
 ?>
```

But when I open it in my browser it shows  only corrupted image icon why???

Comment: Uncomment the header and see if there are any warning. (Possibly the font isn't found)

Comment: imagettftext(): Problem loading glyph in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywork\jinse.php on line 27

Comment: Is face.ttf in the same folder as the php script?

Comment: yes... this code was working fine a few hours ago. But I don't know whats wrong happened then..

Comment: Try `__DIR__ . 'face.ttf'` instead of only `'face.ttf'`